# How can I make a coloured footrule using fancyhdr?

Tags: color, fancyhdr

I found this on the Internet:

```
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to \headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
```

So I was wondering if there are any other solutions, that are more simple or just more understandable.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to \headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
```

Comment: @samcarter I don't have some problems. I just want to know how to make a colored footrule, and I found the code that works for me, but I want to know if there are any other options.

Comment: @samcarter Okay, I added MWE to the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is really easier than to just add the colour to the definition of the footline, but another method could be patch the command by adding the red colour before and switching back to black afterwards:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\footrule}{\color{black}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\footrule}{\color{red}}{}{}


\begin{document}

x

\newpage

x

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. You said I can add the colour to the defenition of the footline. Could you tell me more about this?
@samcarter

Comment: @Vlashious Adding the colour directly to the footrule definition is what you do in the code in your question

Answer (score 4):

The definition you are using for the `\footrule` is actually a little different to the default one contained in `fancyhdr.sty`, which is:

```
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
```

It's not really necessary to understand this to use it. That's half the point of a package.

To make it coloured, you want to put `\color{red}` at the start of the command, but after the brace that is immediately before `\if@fancyplain`. Puting it within the group will ensure that the colour does not continue beyond the rule.

I would do this by patching `\footnoterule` using the `etoolbox` package. Something like this (I also prefer `xcolor` to `color`—nicer features):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\footrule}
  {\if@fancyplain}
  {\color{red}\if@fancyplain}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

[image: output]